# Host name may not be null while using HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient, hostname, androidhttpclient

I am developing an app in android. I am using web services in android. I just changed url for web services. I added underScore(_) in url.

I am getting this error "Host name may not be null while using httpClient". I found that there was a issue of underScore while using HttpClient.

From [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-911) and [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6587184), I have found that bug was filed for this. 
But I couldn't find a solution for this.

**Note** : I am using HttpClient for this. So I don't want to change implementation to something else unless I have to.

How I can use underscore in host name while calling web services using HttpClient ?

Comment: show the url in your code. I guess there might be white space at the starting of url

Comment: It's because of underscore(_) in url. You can read these two articles which i have given link to.

Comment: Still if someone wants to see code i can add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache doesn't support underscore. So when I changed it to dash(-), it started working.

Source : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-911